# LINQPad - Log Secondary DataContext to "SQL" Tab

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

Its easy enough to instantiate multiple DataContexts in LINQPad.  Is there any way to set these instances to Log to the "SQL" Tab of the results pane?

Setting myDataContext.Log = this.Log doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SQL tab output writer is now exposed in the latest LINQPad build:

```
myDataContext.Log = Util.SqlOutputWriter;
```

The latest build also refreshes both results and SQL output in real-time.

Comment: You sir, are a legend.  Thanks again for making my life easier.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use this with EF Core?

Answer (score 1):

The author doesn't expose this currently, the output doesn't really behave in a steam-like way.  (Refreshed on result/action instead of a constant paint)

However, you can request features for [LINQPad on UserVoice](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions), and hope that it makes a future release.

Comment: This answer has been obsolete for quite a long time.